# anti-alias image on python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, antialiasing

I have a simple code in python 3.X to add anti-alias to a .PNG image, I've been succeed tried it by resizing the image 4 times smaller, here the code:

```
def resize(surf, size):
"""
Anti-aliasing by average of color code in four pixels
with subsequent use of the average in a smaller surface
"""
new_surf = pygame.surface.Surface((768,480))
#take sample on the picture
for j in range(0, 480, 2):
    for i in range(0, 768, 2):
        r1, g1, b1, a1 = surf.get_at((i, j))
        r2, g2, b2, a2 = surf.get_at((i+1, j))
        r3, g3, b3, a3 = surf.get_at((i, j+1))
        r4, g4, b4, a4 = surf.get_at((i+1, j+1))

 #averaging the sample
        r1all = (r1 + r2 + r3 + r4) / 4
        g1all = (g1 + g2 + g3 + g4) / 4
        b1all = (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) / 4
        a1all = (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4) / 4

 #put new value on the sample
        new_surf.set_at((i//2, j//2), (r1all, g1all, b1all, 255))

new_size = size
return new_surf, new_size
```

I want to try if I may not need to resize the image by changing this code, I hope the anti-alias effect still can appear.

```
#put new value on the sample
        new_surf.set_at((i, j), (r1all, g1all, b1all, 255))
```

but after try not to resize the image, the result weird and dark like in this image:
[image: failed result, left: failed result, right image: zoom from failed result]

My question, can you guys tell me what is the problem? how to fix this? my goal: make the image still clear white without resizing picture resolution, but the result same as the picture success 'AA example with resizing 4x smaller'

I heard some reference to use super-sampling AA but I have no idea how to apply it.

original image:
[image: original image]

AA example with resizing 4x smaller:
[image: success AA example with resizing 4x smaller]

Comment: I don't understand why you claim your first image is a failure but the second isn't; they are different starting images. Put another way, the "pointillist" image is not amenable to AA. Nobody here is likely to diagnose your big code chunks, especially when you explain the problem poorly. Finally, pygame is a wildly inefficient way to do raster operations.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I've simplified my post. I only want to know, is there any way to apply AA based on my code without resizing the original image?